# Load page without refresh with label form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, url

I am tring to load result on page true list of checkbox

i have this code here - http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/

and i want to do somthing like this:

```
$("#form_id").delegate("input", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

but i got in the end of the url - #undefined

my form is:

```
<form name="search" action="" method="get" id="search_form">

    <div class="fluid">
      <div style="padding-right: 5px; ">        

                         <label> computer <input class="chkd" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="category[]" value="computers"> </label>
                         <label> computer <input class="chkd" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="category[]" value="computers1"> </label>
                         <label> computer <input class="chkd" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="category[]" value="computers2"> </label>

   </div> </div>
</form>
```

any idea?

Comment: What is your HTML? `input` does not have an `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Original article uses:

```
 $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });
```

Means it refers to the `a` tag in `nav`. but in your code, seems like you are trying to get the `href` of an `input`. which is not possible.

Try this:

```
window.location.hash = $("nav a").attr("href");
```

instead of:

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
```

just refer to the right `a` tag.

Comment: @Yaakov what are you trying to achieve? update hash with the value of checked box?

Then this could help:
`window.location.hash = $(this).val();`

Comment: also, instead of `$("#form_id")` use `$("#search_form")`

Comment: i need to add to url "name=value" of the field to url, like = $(this).val() = $(this).name()

Comment: please provide an example of what you want to do? do you want to add `hash` to url like `#name=computer1`?

Comment: exemple- index.php?&category[]=computers&category[]=computers1

Comment: @YaakovSwissa do want the names and values to added to current page or to be sent to another?

Use something like:
`var loc = $('#search_form').serialize(); window.location.href = 'example-index.php?+loc'  `